# Can I make a big explosion when I shoot an arrow?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

Can I testfor shot arrows and then make them explode?

Good would be if this would work only for player-shot arrows. Or, even better, **could I do that when anybody shoots the arrow *from a specific bow* (somehow named or with another NBT tag), it explodes?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can. Here's how:

1. Execute this command:

   ```
   /scoreboard objectives add selector dummy
   ```
2. Give yourself a Power 6 and Infinity (optional) bow (impossible to get in survival) and an arrow:

   ```
   /give @p minecraft:bow 1 0 {ench:[{id:48,lvl:6}, {id:51, lvl:1}]}  
   /give @p minecraft:arrow 1
   ```
3. Power a Repeating Command Block with this command:

   ```
   /scoreboard players add @e[type=Arrow] selector 1 {damage:5.5d,inGround:1b}
   ```

   This will select all arrows fired from a power 6 bow (with damage 5.5) that are in the ground.
4. Next to the last Command Block place two Chain Command Blocks (in a row) - with a Fireball summon command and arrow killing command (at the edge):

   ```
   /execute @e[type=Arrow,score_selector_min=1] ~ ~ ~ /summon Fireball ~ ~ ~ {direction:[0.0,-9.0,0.0],ExplosionPower:15}  
   /kill @e[type=Arrow,score_selector_min=1]
   ```
5. Go shoot your bow out! Good luck!

P.S. If it lags your Minecraft, lower the ExplosionPower value.